# C++ - Visual studio code doesn't recognize <concepts> elements header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++20

So I'm learning about ***concepts*** in C++ and when I try to apply it on Visual Studio Code it doesn't recognize the "requires" and "integral" keywords

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
        
template <typename T>
requires std::integral<T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
   return a + b;
}
    
int main()
    {
    
        char a_0{10};
        char a_1{20};
    
        auto result_a = add(a_0, a_1);
        std::cout << "result_a : " << static_cast<int>(result_a) << std::endl;
    
        int b_0{11};
        int b_1{5};
        auto result_b = add(b_0, b_1);
        std::cout << "result_b : " << result_b << std::endl;
    
        double c_0{11.1};
        double c_1{1.9};
        auto result_c = add(c_0, c_1);
        std::cout << "result_c : " << result_c << std::endl;
    
        return 0;
}
```

Note : I'm using the gcc compiler version 12.2.0

Comment: Are you compiling with C++20?

Comment: "integral" isn't a keyword, it's an ordinary identifier in namespace std

Comment: What compiler and version are you using ? (note VSC is an IDE and can use many compilers)

Comment: I'm using the gcc compiler 12.2.0

Comment: What does "it doesn't recognize the "requires" and "integral" keywords" mean, specifically?

Comment: Requires `-std=c++20` to get further - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Y7f94jn6M default is probably c++17.